# Server stops responding, can't find issue?

Tags: linux, centos

I've had a pretty basic server up and running CentOS with webserver/database, and have noticed that it has locked up a few times in the middle of the night.  It seems to happen randomly.

When it locks up I can ssh in, (although it seems to hang once connected), but can't access cpanel/whm and have to reboot the server to get everything back up.

Checking the messages log I see the below like clockwork every 5minutes 1 second, and then it just stops logging anything until I reboot.  I can't seem to find any log showing any issue?  Is there somewhere I can check to try to figure out what is happening?

Could this be caused by CPU being maxed?

```
Nov 17 08:01:35 s1 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__Q13SKrtaCJCHjBezTfU8Iqmsi@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
Nov 17 08:06:36 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Nov 17 08:06:36 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__mxidFBSnQXmR0QzqSxlqrXLIH0CmJ0GPh9bZ5V3 is now l
ogged in
Nov 17 08:06:37 s1 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__mxidBDaCgnqSxlqrXLIH0CmJ0GPh9bZ5V3@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
Nov 17 08:11:37 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Nov 17 08:11:38 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__T4B7F71acf1dsdJSeJHdqKNcbOdpzNnN_GttgcM is now l
ogged in
Nov 17 08:11:38 s1 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__T4B7F71acf1KNcbOdpzNnN_GttgcM@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
Nov 17 08:16:38 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Nov 17 08:16:38 s1 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__W5C1RzumtaNwe4cU8Lt1 is now logged in
Nov 17 08:16:38 s1 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__W5C1Rzumta03Nwe4cU8Lt1@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.


Nov 17 09:10:58 s1 kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Nov 17 09:10:58 s1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2" x-pid="1094" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Nov 17 09:10:58 s1 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Comment: So, the server got stuck at/around `Nov 17 08:16:38`?

Comment: possible disk/io problem. Is the hd on a SAN?

Comment: @AndreasM Its local storage on a cloud server.

Comment: @BartDeVos Yes, sometime between 8:16:38 and 8:21:39

Comment: Managed to lock it up again today.  I think it might be related to a mysql query.

Comment: TIME+ mysqld - 5130067h, rsyslogd - 5124095h.   I'm guessing those numbers are bigger than they should be....?

Comment: Logs were written to this time.  It looks like theres something causing MySQL to jump up to 1400%CPU, all other tasks get blocked which ends up locking everything up.

Answer (score 1):

We had this a couple of times with Intel-CPUs. This happens when there is nothing to do for the CPUs. Disable the C-sleep-states in the BIOS. Please update your question with your hardware details...

On the other hand - we only had this issue with W2K8R2 and I`ve seen this issue with Debian/Ubuntu as well (in this forum).

I was not aware CentOS (BTW - which version?) triggers the C-sleep-state. CentOS 5 does normally only throttle down the CPU frequency.